# Running VNC fullscreen with multiple monitors

Tags: vnc, monitors

I'm connecting to a remote system using VNC (tigervnc-1.1.0 on client, RealVNC-4.1.2 on server).  The client system has two monitors using Nvidia twinview, with an effective resolution of 3200x1200.

When I tell vncviewer to use fullscreen, the remote system window (1600x1200) is centered across both monitors with large black spaces on both sides.  I also tried running Xinerama instead of twinview on the client system, but this doesn't make any difference.

Is there any way to run vncviewer in fullscreen mode, without the VNC frame, but restrict it a single monitor?

Answer (score 6):

I am using TigerVNC 1.7.1 (32 bit).

```
Start viewer.
Press F8
Selection Options.
Select screens tab.
Check/Uncheck Enable full screen mode over all monitors.
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. Get a newer version of Tigervnc (1.3.0 or later).  Or use Realvnc (which unfortunately is proprietary, and therefore not included in most GNU/Linux distros).

This bug tracker
http://sourceforge.net/p/tigervnc/feature-request-tracker/37/
Implies that it has been fixed in more recent versions of tigervnc.

Also, the best rated answer by Cameron Ton does not exactly answer the question:  There is no "expert" tab the *Tigervnc client* asked about in the original question (there is such a tab in the *Realvnc client*, in my version (5.1.0) there is no parameter UseAllMonitors, but the Fullscreen option appears only on one Monitor). (Apologies: I would have commented on his answer directly, but apparently that requires more reputation that writing an answer).

Answer (score 4):

Is there any way to run vncviewer in fullscreen mode, without the VNC frame, but restrict it a single monitor?

**Yes**.  Go to Options -> Expert Tab and set UseAllMonitors to False.

Answer (score 0):

From "I also tried running Xinerama instead of twinview" I deduct you are using Linux. I don't know tigervnc, but most X programs support the -geometry option which works like this:

```
myprogram -geometry <width>x<height>+<xoffset>+<yoffset>
```

so you probably want to pass your tigervnc

```
-geometry 1600x1200+0+0
```

Actually I think every program linked against Xlib has this feature, so your chances of tigervnc supporting the geometry option are quite good.

Comment: -geometry doesn't seem to do anything